# amplify push causing error : An error occurred during the push operation \app\src\main\res\raw contains invalid WIN32 path characters

Tags: android, aws-sdk, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I'm trying to integrate AWS authentication in my android application, I'm using AWS amplify.
While trying to use `amplify push` command i received following error.

`An error occurred during the push operation: app\src\main\res\raw contains invalid WIN32 path characters.`

I'm pushing below category:

```
| Category | Resource name              | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | -------------------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Auth     | <My Resource name>         | Create    | awscloudformation |
```

Please if someone could help me solving this issue.

Comment: When doing `amplify init`, what have you put the res directory path as?

Comment: Hi @SaurabhThorat I'm putting `app/src/main/res`

Comment: Just a guess, maybe try separating the path with "\" instead of "/"

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thanks for your answer I've tried this while I was referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719364/error-in-aws-cli-amplify-when-executing-the-amplify-init-command-in-windows  but still getting same error.

Comment: Might be a bug. Can you log it here? https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues